# How to send event in xamarin android on LoadUrl from custom WebViewClient?

Tags: c#, android, webview

I have a webview that starts dial tel number from url with OverrideUrlLoading and now after deploying the app events are not firing. How can I send an event after LoadUrl from custom WebViewClient?

```cs
public class OmaWeb : ContentPage{
    ...

    frame = new Frame
       {
                Padding = new Thickness(5),
                BackgroundColor = Color.White,
                Opacity = 1,
                CornerRadius = 10,
                Content = loading
            };

            layout = new StackLayout
            {
                Margin = new Thickness(150, 300, 150, 0),
                Children =
                {
                    frame
                }
     };

    //not firing
    webView.Navigated += (object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs args) =>{
       layout.IsVisible = false; // should hide the layout of spinner
    };
}
```

WebViewRender.cs

```cs
 public class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient{
    Activity mActivity = null;

    public CustomWebViewClient(Activity activity){
        mActivity = activity;
    }

   public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(Android.Webkit.WebView view, IWebResourceRequest request)
            {
       if (request.Url.ToString().StartsWith("tel:"))
       {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionDial, request.Url);
          mActivity.StartActivity(intent);
       }
       else
       {
          view.LoadUrl(request.Url.ToString());
       }
                
       return true;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. What I did is I added a WebView renderer as parameter of my custom WebViewClient

```cs
WebviewRenderer _renderer = null;

            public CustomWebViewClient(WebviewRenderer renderer, Activity activity)
            {
                mActivity = activity;
                _renderer = renderer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("renderer");
            }
```

then I override OnPageFinished method to send navigated event.

```
public override void OnPageFinished(Android.Webkit.WebView view, string url)
            {
                base.OnPageFinished(view, url);

                var source = new UrlWebViewSource { Url = url };
                var args = new WebNavigatedEventArgs(WebNavigationEvent.NewPage, source, url, WebNavigationResult.Success);
                _renderer.ElementController.SendNavigated(args);
            }
```

This article helped me
[enter link here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/138821/navigating-on-android-webview-doesnt-always-fire)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).